# Cordova Build on Android Not Using Code from WWW Folder

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I'm using cordova to package up a pre written angular js application by placing the contents of the app into the www folder inside the cordova sturcture and running the following commands:

```
cordova platform add ios

cordova build ios

cordova emulate ios
```

The app then loads on the ios emulator, but instead of the app content as I would expect to see, it shows the hello cordova index file. I have done the exact same thing for android and it works perfectly on that and shows the app correctly. Any help with finding out why the default cordova index page is still shown would be great thanks.

Comment: Tell us in which folder exactly (!) you have your contents now. cordova build will ever run the code from the root www folder.

Comment: my base app folder is ~/Documents/apps/ios-cordova and inside that folder is config.xml, hooks, platforms, plugins and the www folder where I have pasted my app code.

Comment: Your app code has to go inside (!) the www folder

Comment: Yeah, I had it inside the folder. Have got it working now, I'll post an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed to get it working. When I built the code using cordova, I then opened the xcode.proj file in xcode, and that has done something to some of the files, and it was causing the app to crash at the splash screen. This is why I thought it was not using the www/ code as the splash screen is almost identical to the hello cordova default index file.

Using the cordova emulate command line option to run the app without touching xcode allows the app to run correctly.